# The text from the_content() appears as a single line extending out of the container

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg9P7.png)When I use `the_content` in the code below, the text doesn't respect the container:

[image: Overflowing text]

I've done this before and this never happened.

```
<?php $html = ghc_featured_image(get_the_ID());
    //** $html[0] returns HTML **
    //** $html[1] returns if the image exists **

    echo $html[0];
    ?>

<main class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="py-3 px-5 about-content border-rd bg-light <?php echo $html[1] ? 'col-md-8' : 'col-md-12 m-0' ?>">
               <h1 class="text-center my-5 separator"> <?php the_title()?> </h1>
               <?php the_content();?>
          </div> <!-- col-md-8 -->
     </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Must be css conflict. It should work with HTML and bootstrap. Go to console and debug the css conflict

Comment: Could find any css conflict, do not what to do

Comment: It looks like something is preventing the text from wrapping, so if its not the CSS then check the actual text in the content - it might have non-breaking spaces for example. But there is nothing wrong with the code you have shown us and that is the only information we have bout your site, so there isn't much else other help we can offer without more details.

Comment: Can you try the following `<?php echo wpautop( get_the_content() ); ?>`.. We are using `wpautop()` to replaces double line breaks with paragraph on the content.

Comment: Hi guys I tried all of that and didn't work I remember that I updated WordPress, I reinstalled the older version and worked just fine, With the new one it creates non-breaking spaces as you mentioned @FluffyKitten, but the older version doesn't. Still hope I can fix this in the future.